# XQuery : how to get the previous element than the one chosen in an XML file?

Tags: xml, xquery, exist-db

Well if I have for example:

```
<entries>
  ...
  <entry id="34" weight="83">...</entry>
  <entry id="35" weight="21">...</entry>
  ...
</entries>
```

For any reason I get the entry whose ID is 35: `let $entry := //entry[xs:integer(./@weight)=21]`. How can I simply get the previous entry (ID 34) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use XPath axis `preceding-sibling` to fetch all preceding siblings, than limit the result set to the last one.

```
(//entry[xs:integer(./@weight)=21]/preceding-sibling::*)[last()]
```

Depending on your data set and XQuery implementation, it could be faster to go the other way round: Find the `<entry/>` elements which are followed by one fulfilling the condition.

```
//entry[./following-sibling::*[1][xs:integer(./@weight)=8]]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
//entry[xs:integer(@weight)=21]/preceding-sibling::entry[1]
```

The preceding-sibling axis counts backwards. `[1]` denotes the immediately preceding sibling.